# Chess board that will check if a piece entered onto the board is in a valid position

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am very new to Java programming in general and have just started using 2D arrays. What I am trying to do is make a program that creates a chessboard 8x8, and asks the user to input strings (pieces) to be stored on the chessboard. For now, I dont want to check whether or not the piece is a valid chess piece, but I want to make sure that the placement is valid (i.e. when prompted to place a piece and the user chooses an invalid coordinate, the program will tell the user that its wrong). Otherwise, if the coordinate is right, it will store the string, which I will use another class to print the string(s) and output them, as well as where they are placed, to the user. Since it is a chess board, I am trying to convert 8x8 to 8 followed by a character from a-g.

Heres what I have so far:

```java
public class ChessBoard {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char rows = 'a';
        String spot;
        int[][] grid = new int[8][8];
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++, rows++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid[i].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(rows + "" + (col + 1) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This prints the layout of the chessboard, but I am not sure how to ask the user for a string in a valid coordinate, say, e5, which can then be printed in another class.

I would want my expected output to be something like:

```
Enter a coordinate: a5
Enter a piece to be placed here: Queen
```

Continue until the user wishes to see what they have placed:

```
You have placed a Queen at a5
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Generally, you can use a [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read input from the console.

Answer (score 2):

To get the position from the user, you can use something like

```
// only once, to initialize the scanner
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// each time you need input from the user
String input = scanner.next();
```

To ask for a position, you can check whether the input matches what you expect, and request a new input otherwise:

```
String input = null;              // will be changed to a valid position
boolean iLikeThisInput = false;   // will be true if position is valid
while ( ! iLikeThisInput) {
   System.out.println("Enter a coordinate (for example, a5): ");
   input = scanner.next();
   iLikeThisInput = input.matches("[a-g][1-8]");  // this is a regular expression
};
// now we now that the input is valid
int col = (int)(input.charAt(0) - 'a'); // 'a' is column 0: 'a' - 'a' = 0.
int row = (int)(input.charAt(1) - '0'); // '0' is row 0: same trick
```

[Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are probably new for you (if you are new to programming), but are very powerful to check if text matches a certain pattern, and found across all major programming languages.

The trick of substracting character codes (last 2 lines) works because the characters codes for digits `0123456789` and those for the alphabet `abcd`... are in numerical/alphabetical order, so that writing `(int)('b'-'a')` is the same as writing `1`.

You will just be missing the code to get the piece. A regular expression for a lot of words can be built easily by using `|`:

```
 input.matches("Bob|Robert|Rob"); // matches only Bob or Robert or Rob
```

The final piece is to convert from integers to piece-names and vice-versa. I recommend writing two methods:

```
 public static String pieceToName(int piece) { /**/ }
```

and

```
 public static int nameToPiece(String name) { /**/ }
```

Using the `switch` statement, you can quickly implement both with your preferred encoding:

```
 switch(name) {
   case "Queen": return 9;
   case "Pawn":  return 1;
   ...
 }
```

Note that if you start to build an actual chess-playing program, you will have to distinguish between white and black pieces. One way of doing it is to use positive numbers for one color, and negative for the other.

Good luck with your program!

Comment: Thanks very much! This is extremely helpful, although, when trying to implement the input.charAt, I get errors which state that it cannot find the symbol located at input. Is this because input needs to be declared earlier? Thanks!

Comment: I would need to see the full program. However, my answer is more a collection of hints than a complete chess program - there are many of those online if you only want one that works (and the good ones use "bitboards", and not 2d arrays). If you want to learn, on the other hand, you will have to find many answers on your own.

Comment: The code I posted was my full program, but I have implemented some parts of yours into mine. However, the only compiler errors I get are in the 2 lines of your code "int col =(int)(input.charAt(0) and "int row (...)". The error is that it could not find the symbol "input" and i'm not too sure why. Like I said, I am designing a very simple structure which only asks the user to input pieces on the board rather than making the entire game. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the code in my answer, by moving the declaration of `input` outside the loop.